# Erro ao povoar combobox - An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, combobox, lista, winforms

Este é um cod. para preencher um combobox com um list que sera popula atraves do evento inserir que resgatará um valor de uma textbox, e irá fazer com que o nome selecionado na combobox1 não aparece na combobox 2 e assim respectivamente.

Estou com um erro no inserir. Onde Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Coleção foi modificada; talvez a operação de enumeração não seja executada.

```
//arrays
public List<ComboBox> combos;
public List<string> originalSource = new List<string> {"Nome1", "Nome2"};
public List<object> selectedItems = new List<object>();
//############################ ---Errrrro --- #########################
private void inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in originalSource)
    {
        String _Temp = "";
        _Temp = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        originalSource.Add(_Temp);
    }
}

//povoar combos
private void InitializeCombos()
{
    combos = new List<ComboBox> { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
    combos.ForEach(combo =>
    {
        originalSource.ForEach(item => combo.Items.Add(item));
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged += RemoveOptionFromCombo;
    });
}
//Remover intens duplicados
private void RemoveOptionFromCombo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    selectedItems = new List<object> 
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedItem, comboBox2.SelectedItem, comboBox3.SelectedItem
    };

    combos.ForEach(combo =>
    {
        originalSource.ForEach(item =>
        {
            if (!combo.Items.Contains(item) && !selectedItems.Contains(item))
                combo.Items.Add(item);
            if (combo.Items.Contains(item) && selectedItems.Contains(item) && !item.Equals(combo.SelectedItem))
                combo.Items.Remove(item);
        });
    });
}
```

Obs: o erro somente aparece ao acionar o evento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode modificar uma coleção dentro de uma iteração [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).

Use uma iteração `for`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < originalSource.Count; i++)
{
    String _Temp = "";
    _Temp = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    originalSource.Add(_Temp);
}
```

Comment: Bernardo o erro persiste. Vejam melhor:
[http://www.sendspace.com/file/5mq3qo]

Comment: Baixei sua aplicação, o erro não acontece mais. O que acontece agora é uma iteração infinita, visto que para cada item da lista, é adicionado um novo item. Para o novo item adicionado, é adicionado um novo item, e assim por diante, infinitamente. Isso é um erro de lógica. Para resolver, é necessário entender exatamente qual o objetivo do código.

Comment: Realmente havia um erro de lógica, modifiquei: `private void inserir_Click(object sender, EventArgse) { originalSource.Add(textBox1.Text.ToString()); }` **O objetivo e quando o evento click for disparado ele adicione o que estava na texbox na list e depois povoe as combobox com o que tem dentro da mesma** _O erro se encontra agora em outro local pois os novos itens não aparecem nas combobox's_

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código resposta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExemploLista  
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> pessoas = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        { pessoas.Add(string.Format("Valor {0}", i)); }

        this.InitializeControls();
    }

    private void InitializeControls(ComboBox control = null)
    {
        List<string> dataSource = this.FilterData();

        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item is ComboBox )
            {
                if ((ComboBox)item != control)
                {
                    this.PopulateControl((ComboBox)item, dataSource);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.PopulateControl((ComboBox)item, dataSource, control.Text);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private List<string> FilterData()
    {
        List<string> usedValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item is ComboBox)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ComboBox)item).Text))
                { usedValues.Add(((ComboBox)item).Text); }
            }
        }

        var result = from s in this.pessoas
                     where !usedValues.Contains(s)
                     select s;

        return result.ToList();
    }

    private void PopulateControl(ComboBox control, List<string> datasource, string text = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            foreach (var item in datasource)
            {
                if (item != text && control.Items.IndexOf(item) == -1)
                {
                    control.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            control.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in datasource)
            { 
                control.Items.Add(item); 
            }
        }
    }

    private void CombomBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InitializeControls((ComboBox)sender);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pessoas.Add(textBox1.Text);
        this.InitializeControls();
        textBox1.Clear();
    }

}
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Parece que você está com dificuldades na formatação, confira o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help. É legal também explicar *porque* seu código resolve o problema, veja [answer]. Na verdade, parece que o comentário que fez na resposta do Bernardo é a explicação e falta nesta resposta.